# The content of the div that has been replaces don't follow the js ruls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ssl

I'm using this code to disable the default behavior of the element `<a>` and replace the content of the `<div>` with the `id` **MyDiv** with the content of the URL that is in the `<a>` element that was clicked

```
$(function(){
    EnderReact();
});
function EnderReact(){
    $("a").on("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(!(($(this).attr('href')).replace(/\s/g, '') > 0)){
            var TheURL = $(this).attr('href');
        }
        if(TheURL && !(TheURL.indexOf("http") > -1 || TheURL.indexOf("https") > -1 || TheURL.indexOf("//") > -1)){
            TheURL = "https://example.com/" + TheURL + "?v=1";
            $("#MyDiv").load(TheURL , 
                function(response, status, xhr) {
                    EnderReact();
                    if (status == "error")
                        alert(xhr.status + " (" + xhr.statusText + ")");
                    else
                        alert(xhr.status + " (" + xhr.statusText + ")");
                });
        }
  });
}
```

and I use this `<meta>` tag to allow the function to not return an error in the `https://` version of the website:

```
<meta id="EnderSystem--meta" http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

now, when I first replace the content of the div for the first time it keeps lisiting to that function, but in the secound time it just do the defult behavior, **How can I fix that?**

Comment: I did not get your question clearly but one thing I have noticed that the event is not exist in your current function and to fix this replace this with yours 

$("a").on("click", function (event) {

Comment: Umm, `  $("a").on("click", function () ` exists in the line 5

Comment: $("a").on("click", function (event) {

Compare your 5th line with the above one... be careful while comparing the line.

To prevent the action you must pass the event in the function parameter.

Comment: No, I've tried that, and it didn't work, anyway I've solved the problem

Comment: @EnderHostsAccount If you've solved the problem, please either write an answer or remove your question.